# Separate words and numbers into 2 separate lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I am making a program that has a dictionary of both words and numbers. I need the program to go through the dictionary and separate the words and the numbers into two separate lists. Next, I need to prompt the user to choose to print the numbers, words or both. I am struggling a lot with this question. I am very new to Python so any help would be great. Here is what I have so far:

```
dictionary = {"Maciek": 1, "Marek": 2, "Marcel":3, "Karolina":4, "Renata":5}

words = []
numbers = []

print("The following dictionary is here as presented:", dictionary)
print("To print all of the numbers, please type NUM, to print all the words, please type WORD")
user_input = input("Please choose which of the two you want to see printed: ")


if user_input == "NUM":
    for num in dictionary:
        dictionary.append(numbers)
        print("Here are the numbers in the list: ", numbers)


if user_input == "WORD":
    for alpha in dictionary:
        words.append(dictionary)
        print("Here are the words in the list: ", words)


elif user_input != "WORD" or user_input != "NUM" or user_input.isdigit():
    print("You made an invalid input, please try again!")
    user_input = input("Please choose which of the two you want to see printed: ")
```

I am not sure what else to do from here. If anyone has anything they would change to the code, I'd really appreciate the input. Please show the change in code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `dictionary.keys()` and `dictionary.values()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary.keys() and dictionary.values() to accomplish this

```
dictionary = {"Maciek": 1, "Marek": 2, "Marcel":3, "Karolina":4, "Renata":5}

words = []
numbers = []

print("The following dictionary is here as presented:", dictionary)
print("To print all of the numbers, please type NUM, to print all the words, please type WORD")
user_input = input("Please choose which of the two you want to see printed: ")

if user_input == "NUM":
    print("Here are the numbers in the list: ", dictionary.values())

elif user_input == "WORD":
    print("Here are the words in the list: ", dictionary.keys())

elif user_input != "WORD" or user_input != "NUM" or user_input.isdigit():
    print("You made an invalid input, please try again!")
    user_input = input("Please choose which of the two you want to see printed: ")
```

However, the way it is currently written, if the user enters something other than "WORD" or "NUM", it won't do anything after accepting new input.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If the user input is WORD, it will print out all the names a bunch of times. What should I do to make it print only once. Also if the input is NUM it prints it but then prints the error message. Anything you would change?

Comment: @MaciekB -- Either: 1) remove the for loop i.e. `for alpha in dictionary:` and just keep the print statement, or 2) change print to use `dictionary[alpha]` rather than `dictionary.keys()`

Comment: Yes, edited to remove the for loop. Sorry, end of day brainfart on that!

Comment: Changed the second `if` to an `elif`, that fixes the error appearing